# $f(x,y) = \begin{cases} \frac{xy^2}{x^2+y^2} \quad \text{if} \ (x,y)\not=(0,0)\\ 0 \quad \text{if} \ (x,y)=(0,0)\end{cases}$ differentiable?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

$$f(x,y) = \begin{cases}  \frac{xy^2}{x^2+y^2} \quad \text{if} \ (x,y)\not=(0,0)\\ 0 \quad \text{if} \ (x,y)=(0,0)\end{cases}$$

Is this two-variable function differentiable at (0,0)?

Comment: It is possible to make the limit be different numbers from different directions, so no.  Consider $y=x$ vs. $y=\sqrt x$.

Comment: @abiessu I think you are wrong. In both case, the value of limit is 0.

Comment: You can consider any line through origin which has a constant slope other than $1$ and other the line $y=x$. Both will give different answers. for example, take $y =2x$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In polar coordinates,
$$f=r\cos\phi\sin^2\phi$$
So that the secant of $f$ from the origin in the direction $(\cos\phi,\sin\phi)$ to radius $r$ has slope
$$\frac{\mathrm{d}f}{\mathrm{d}r}=\frac{\Delta f}{\Delta r}=\cos\phi\sin^2\phi\text{.}$$
Therefore $f$ is [Gâteaux differentiable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gateaux_derivative) at the origin—it has a directional derivative in all directions.

However, there are no constants $f_x$, $f_y$ such that
$$\frac{\mathrm{d}f}{\mathrm{d}r}=f_x\cos\phi+f_y\sin\phi\text{.}$$
That is, the directional derivatives are not linear in the direction. We say, then, that $f$ is not [Fréchet differentiable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fr%C3%A9chet_derivative) (without further qualification, the Fréchet derivative is “the” derivative, so $f$ is not differentiable at the origin).

Answer (score 2):

$f(x,y) = \begin{cases}  \frac{xy^2}{x^2+y^2} \quad \text{if} \ (x,y)\not=(0,0)\\ 0 \quad \text{if} \ (x,y)=(0,0)\end{cases}$

Here $$f_x(0,0)= \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(h,0)-f(0,0)}{h}=0$$

$$f_y(0,0)= \lim_{k\to 0} \frac{f(0,k)-f(0,0)}{k}=0$$

So the first order partial derivatives with respect to $x$ and $y$ both exist at $(0,0)$.

If the given function is differentiable at $(0,0)$, then by definition

$df=f(h,k)-f(0,0)=Ah+Bk+h\phi+k\psi$ . . . . $(1)$

where $A=f_x(0,0)=0$; $B=f_y(0,0)=0$; and $\phi$, $\psi$ tends to zero as $(h,k)\to(0,0)$.

From $(1)$, $ \frac{hk^2}{h^2+k^2}=h\phi+k\psi$

Putting $k=mh$ and letting $h\to0$, we get

$\frac{m^2}{1+m^2}=\lim_{h \to 0}(\phi+m\psi)=0$

which is impossible for arbitrary $m$.

Hence the given function is **not differentiable** at $(0,0)$.

Answer (score 1):

$\frac {\partial f} {dx}=\lim \frac {y^{2}} {x^{2}+y^{2}}$ which does not exist. [Consider limit along $y=0$ and limit along $x=y$]. So $f$ is not differentiable at $(0,0)$.

Answer (score 0):

The question is quite simple.

$f'_x(0,0)=f'_y(0,0)=0$ ,

Let $x=y=t$ then the function become $F(t)=f(t,t)=\frac{t}{2}$. The differentiation is $F'(t)=\frac{1}{2}\ne 0$ then it is not differentiable.

Answer (score 0):

*Another way would be to answer the original question by definition.*

For contradiction, assume that the function is differentiable at $(0,0)$. In virtue of the fact that $f(0,0)=f'_x(0,0)=f'_y(0,0)=0$, it suffices to show that

$$
f(h_x,h_y)=f(0,0)+f'_x(0,0)\cdot h_x+f'_y(0,0)\cdot h_y+\varepsilon (h_x,h_y)
$$

with $\frac{\varepsilon (h_x,h_y)}{\sqrt{h_x^2+h_y^2}}\to 0$ as $(h_x,h_y)\to (0,0)$. Since the first three summands on the RHS vanish, we obtain $\varepsilon(h_x,h_y)=f(h_x,h_y)$. Consequently,

$$
\frac{\varepsilon (h_x,h_y)}{\sqrt{h_x^2+h_y^2}}
=\frac{h_x^2\,h_y}{\sqrt{\left (h_x^2+h_y^2\right )^3}}
$$

which is a non-constant homogeneous function of degree $0$. Therefore, $\frac{\varepsilon (h_x,h_y)}{\sqrt{h_x^2+h_y^2}}\,{\color{red}\not{\!\!{\color{red}\to}}}\,0$ as $(h_x,h_y)\to (0,0)$ and $f(x,y)$ cannot be differentiable at $(0,0)$.